# setting ulimit and ubuntu 8.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ulimit, files

We have two ubuntu 8.04 servers.
With the database server I set the table_cache to 1000 however when I restart mysql the status only shows 257 and the open files limit says 1024

I adjusted ulimit by doing
ulimit -n 8192
and then restarting mysql; this seemed to do the tick however after a few hours I did
ulimit -n and saw it had returned back to 1024

Bit of a worry.

I edited the /etc/security/limits.conf
and added

`mysql soft nofile 8192`

`mysql hard nofile 8192`

then rebooted, no change.
I then edited and change mysql to *
rebooted, no change
I then edited and changed it to one line

`* - nofile 8192`

and rebooted, no change.

`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`
gives me 768730

`sysctl fs.file-max`
gives me `fs.file-max = 768730`

I am at a bit of a loss to how I can set and keep the ulimit value set so I can increase the table cache properly on mysql.

Comment: Are you checking ulimit in the same shell that launches mySQL? If not the answer may not be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

[edit: explained details for clarity]

I suspect you checked the ulimit for the different user than mysql ;)

You don't have to reboot after changing `limits.conf`. You have to turn on use of this file in the corresponding PAM service in `/etc/pam.d/`.

Do `grep pam_limits /etc/pam.d/*` to have a clue in which situation `limits.conf` will be used.

For example, change in `limits.conf` for can be visible in the shell invoked as `sudo -u user bash` but doesn't when run as `sudo su - user` - that's because on Ubuntu default setting goes like this:

`$ grep limits /etc/pam.d/*|grep su

  /etc/pam.d/su:# session    required   pam_limits.so

  /etc/pam.d/sudo:session required pam_limits.so`

So if you checked limits using `sudo su - mysql` then there was a mess -- `su` didn't turn the limits on. You can check which pam service is being run by watching `/var/log/auth.log`.

For all possible types of invocation of your mysql it should be safe to modify `pam.d/other` or just `pam.d/common-session`.

Comment: Ah, this is similar to http://serverfault.com/questions/73894/limits-conf-setting-doesnt-stick I will give this a go; weird how it's pam limits for su and sudo when the process starts when the machines starts or when I do init.d/mysql start/restart

Answer (score 1):

A more straightforward way (and kinda of a hack) is just add the `ulimit -n 8192` command inside the init script for mysql  `/etc/init.d/mysql`. The control is valid for the shell and the child processes/shells that it opens.

EDIT: the `su` and `sudo` 'weirdness' is because the limits.conf file is related to PAM limits that, if I am not mistaken, only applies to login shells. Also, there is some info on `start-stop-daemon` being unable to use the pam limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure about current limits MySQL has, check out the current process id for mysqld with the method of your choice (top, ps aux, pgrep, whatever). Then just type

`sudo cat /proc/mysql_process_id_you_found/limits`

If it doesn't tell you 8192 for the open files, you can always hack around the init script as someone suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add session required pam_limits.so to /etc/pam.d/common-session?