# Increasing file descriptor limit on Debian does not work! Help!

Tags: linux, debian, max-file-descriptors

I am running Debian 6 and I am trying to increase the file descriptor limit but it does not want to work.  This is what I have done:

I edited `/etc/sysctl.conf` by adding `fs.file-max = 64000` at the end and applied the changes using `sysctl -p`.

I then edited `/etc/security/limits.conf` and added the following lines: `* soft nofile 64000` and `* hard nofile 64000`.

Now when I execute `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn` I still see 1024.  I rebooted the server and I still get the same result.  What have I failed to do?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/235356/open-file-descriptor-limits-conf-setting-isnt-read-by-ulimit-even-when-pam-limit

PS: No need to reboot after changing the `/etc/security/limits.conf`, just log out and log back in.

Comment: I did that too but I still get `1024` when executing `ulimit -Hn` and `ulimit -Sn`.  Is this normal?  If I changed the file descriptor hard and soft limit should it not give me the number I set it to?  I am doing this because I run NGINX/PHP-FPM which is running low on descriptors.

Comment: I did not see the link you posted. It solved the problem. Thanks! +1

Answer (score 2):

`grep -lr pam_limits /etc/pam.d`?

If it's not return `common-session`, run the following command:

```
echo -e "session\trequired\t\tpam_limits.so" > /etc/pam.d/common-session
```

logging out and in again to see it works.

Comment: The command you did not work.  But I do see `/etc/pam.d/common-session` in the directory `pam.d` directory.  I'm not sure how that those commands will help, especially in Debian.